# Voltage gain of common emitter amplifier

Tags: common-emitter

I'm posting this question just to be sure I'm understanding this correctly.

I want to estimate the voltage gain of the following common emitter amplifier either as \$A_v=-4.7\$ or \$A_v=-145\$.

[image]

It's pretty obvious that \$A_v=-\frac{R_C}{r_e}<<-4.7\$ due to the shunt capacitor. However, I am asked to estimate the voltage gain at frequencies 1kHz-10kHz. Does anything change at these frequencies? I think I have HPF filters due to the coupling capacitors but I'm not too sure which resistance goes with which capacitor. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: The \$X_C\$ changes with frequency. All capacitors are frequency-dependent devices. You know how to compute it, yes?

Comment: @jonk Of course. I just don't know if I will have different voltage gain from the A_v=-R_C/r_e at low frequencies due to HPF filters.

Comment: Yes, \$r_e\$ must be added to \$X_C\$ as must any Ohmic emitter resistance. You also have two other capacitors that interact. Your output capacitor is low enough that it will affect things added later on as a load. Your input capacitor has a high enough impedance, and your bypass capacitor has a low enough impedance, reflected back to the base, that the gain will be measurably affected, I suspect.

Comment: Keep in mind that \$X_C\$ is out of phase. So it may not affect things a lot. But some.

Comment: So, I should expect a gain of -R_C/R_E=-4.7? I suppose not. I should expect something at the hundreds, right?!

Comment: Yes, I get something close to -137, or so.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe less than that. Sorry.

Comment: Did you simulate the circuit with a program or by the use of formulas?

Comment: Formulas. Your input signal has an unstated source resistance. Assuming the output of the signal generator is \$50\:\Omega\$ (reasonable, because lots of opamps are around there and so are signal generators, too) then your signal will be diminished by the series divider made up of \$50\:\Omega+2.2\:\mu\text{F}\$ and \$22\:\text{k}\Omega\vert\vert 120\:\text{k}\Omega\vert\vert \left(\beta \:X_{100\:\mu\text{F}}\right)\$. Once that divider is worked out (and it has complex impedance), that's your input to the amplifier.

Comment: So, for example, your \$2.2\:\mu\text{F}\$ input cap at \$1\:\text{kHz}\$ is \$72.34\:\Omega\$ at -90 degrees. Add \$50\:\Omega\$ source resistance to that and that's about \$88\:\Omega\$ at -55 degrees. But then, I'm not sure if you are allowed to assume a \$50\:\Omega\$ input resistance from your signal generator.

Comment: The question is really vague and I'm not too sure on what to answer.

Comment: I think they want you to pick the larger magnitude value, if those are your two choices. The emitter current is \$\frac{V_\text{TH}-V_\text{BE}}{R_\text{E}+\frac{R_\text{TH}}{\beta+1}}\$ and this works out to something like \$777\:\mu\text{A}\$. So \$r_e\approx 33.3\:\Omega\$. With the capacitor, \$r_e+X_C\approx 33.4\:\Omega\$ at about -3 degrees angle. So that looks like maybe -140. With the slight losses at the input (1%?), this gets close to that -137 I mentioned earlier. Maybe -138.

Comment: I will choose the largest value then. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Look at the AC equivalent circuit and it will be easier to make these calculations. More info [here](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e84/lectures/ch4/node8.html)